# How does one visualize sequence of derivatives and functions in a same diagram?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Currently I am studying one theorem in real analysis, which states that

> Suppose $(f_n)$ is sequence of differentiable functions on $[a,b]$ and $(f_n')$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$. If there exists $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{f_n(x_0)}$ exists, then there exists a function $f$ such that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$ and $f'=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{f_n'}$.

The main idea of the theorem is that if sequence of derivative functions converges uniformly, then the sequence of original functions also converges uniformly.

Question: How to understand this theorem in a picture? I try to visualize both $(f_n')$ and $(f_n)$ in a same picture but to no avail.

Comment: Graph a couple of functions with Desmos?

Comment: @SimpleArt: Examples?

Comment: What about something like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0foekk9aft)?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that Desmos have this kind of function.

Comment: Desmos is pretty good for graphing derivatives and such...

Comment: This is a vague request, but can you explain what about the theorem doesn't make intuitive sense? Is it the fact you have to assume convergence at one point...? (That hypothesis "fixes the constant of integration".)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Yes, exactly. I don't know why we need that assumption in terms of picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Desmos.com to graph some pretty neat things, for example, see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0foekk9aft).  All you have to do is set some function $f_n(x)$ and some function $g_n(x)=\frac d{dx}f_n(x)$ and have a slider bar for $n$ that goes from $n=1$ to whatever value you want to reach.  It can then animate the transitions as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Without the hypothesis "There exists an $x_{0} \in [a, b]$ such that $\lim f_{n}(x_{0})$ exists", you could have $f_{n} \equiv n$ on $[a, b]$; the derivative sequence is identically zero (so the derivatives converge uniformly to $0$) but the sequence $(f_{n})$ converges nowhere.

Comment: Or somewhat more generally take any function that satisfies the theorem and replace $f_n$ with $f_n + a_n$ where $(a_n)$ is a non-converging sequence of real numbers. You get a sequence of functions that satisfies all the conditions _except_ the limit at $x_0,$ but it doesn't converge.